# How do set props in jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am getting the following error when I run my jest unit test

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `action` is marked as required in `Button`, but its value is `undefined`.
>             in Button
>       console.error node_modules/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js:20
>         Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `path` is marked as required in `Button`, but its value is `undefined`.
>             in Button

I tried creating a const component that creates the component with the values that I set for the props but it still didn't remove the warnings.

```
UNIT TEST
// describe what we are testing
describe('Button Component', () => {

// make our assertion and what we expect to happen 
 it('should render without throwing an error', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
        <Button action={''}
        path={'Cancel'} />)
   expect(shallow(<Button />).find('div.container').exists()).toBe(true)
 })
})

BUTTON JSX
function Button(props) {
const { action, path } = props;
  return (
     ......

  );
}

Button.propTypes = {
  action: string.isRequired,
  path: string.isRequired
};
```

My test 'passes'. Not sure if it's a false positive but I just need the error to go away. Also, how do I verify that the props I passed are there based on clicking the button?

Comment: you are not providing a prop `action` inside `shallow(<Button />)`

Comment: Thanks. Any advice on the last question in my post?

Comment: you want to verify whether action and path are actually used in Button component?

Comment: Yes, just verifying that once I click the button, it has the right action and path that I set

Comment: `renderer.create` and `shallow` are two different ways to render the component (one is `react-test-renderer`, the other is `enzyme`) and you aren't passing `action` when you render with `shallow`.  If you're looking for feedback on testing your `Button` component please share more of the code you are testing, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Button = props => {
  return <div className="container"></div>;
};

Button.propTypes = {
  action: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  path: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Button;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Button from '.';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('Button', () => {
  it('should render without throwing an error ', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<Button action={''} path={'Cancel'} />);
    expect(
      shallow(<Button action={''} path={'Cancel'} />)
        .find('div.container')
        .exists()
    ).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/55766433/index.spec.tsx (10.749s)
  Button
    ✓ should render without throwing an error  (29ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.895s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/55766433